# Weird result of using recursion to concat array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use recursion to build list to array function but the expected result is reversed to real solution. How could I improve the function of **listToArray(list)**

```js
function arrayToList(arr){
    if(arr.length==1){
        return {value:arr.pop(), rest:null};
    }else{
        return {value:arr.pop(), rest: arrayToList(arr)};
    }
}

//weired result can't find answer
function listToArray(list){
    if(list.rest == null){
        return [list.value];
    }else{
        return [list.value].concat(listToArray(list.rest));
    }
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
// → [10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: Well pop removes the last element.... so you are reading the values from the end....

Comment: What is your question? What is weird about the result? What do you want to improve, specifically?

Comment: listToArray should output [10, 20, 30] but the result is [30, 20, 10]

Answer (score 1):

`pop()` removes the last item so you are reading from the end to the start. So read from the start to the end using `shift()`

```js
function arrayToList(arr){
    if(arr.length==1){
        return {value:arr.shift(), rest:null};
    }else{
        return {value:arr.shift(), rest: arrayToList(arr)};
    }
}

//weired result can't find answer
function listToArray(list){
    if(list.rest == null){
        return [list.value];
    }else{
        return [list.value].concat(listToArray(list.rest));
    }
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
// → [10, 20, 30]
```

Comment: Thanks, make a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to concat the other way around, so replace

```
[list.value].concat(listToArray(list.rest));
```

with

```
(listToArray(list.rest)).concat([list.value]);
```

See the snippet below

```js
function arrayToList(arr){
    if(arr.length==1){
        return {value:arr.pop(), rest:null};
    }else{
        return {value:arr.pop(), rest: arrayToList(arr)};
    }
}

//weired result can't find answer
function listToArray(list){
    if(list.rest == null){
        return [list.value];
    }else{
        return (listToArray(list.rest)).concat([list.value]);
    }
}

console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
console.log(listToArray(arrayToList([10, 20, 30])));
// → [10, 20, 30]
```